# How do I set my avatar in Twitter programmatically?

Tags: cocoa, macos, twitter, avatar

I want to write a program that would set my twitter avatar to a random picture in a folder.
I know how to pick out random files, but how do I make them upload to twitter?

Thanks.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You would need to use Twitter's [REST API service](https://dev.twitter.com/).  There is one service in particular that will help you: [POST account/update_profile_image](https://dev.twitter.com/docs/api/1/post/account/update_profile_image).

Note that the API is expecting multipart form data, **not** a URL.

Comment: Do I need to give it ALL the parameters like in example? 0_0

Comment: I'm fairly certain that what you're seeing as an example of the data that would get returned to you.  Assuming you've been authenticated through Twitter's OAuth then you should be able to only send the base64 encoded image.  I freely admit however that I haven't messed around with the Twitter API, just researched it :)

Comment: Could you please provide an example in ruby/python/cocoa/C?